# How to properly reshape values for N-dimensional interpolation with Scipy and 1D arrays?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

Given some data

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D

x = [0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.46,0.46,0.46,0.46,0.46,0.46,0.46,0.46,0.46,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,]
y = [0.01,0.01,0.01,0.255,0.255,0.255,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.255,0.255,0.255,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.255,0.255,0.255,0.5,0.5,0.5,]
z = [0.,0.1,0.2,0.,0.1,0.2,0.,0.1,0.2,0.,0.1,0.2,0.,0.1,0.2,0.,0.1,0.2,0.,0.1,0.2,0.,0.1,0.2,0.,0.1,0.2]
v = [0.,0.,1.,0.,1.,1.,0.,1.,1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.5,1.,0.,1.,1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.5,1.,]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))
c = ax.scatter(x, y, z, c = v, s = 100, cmap = plt.cm.bwr, edgecolor = "black", alpha = 0.2)

ax.scatter(0.51, 0.32, 0.12, s = 100, c = "black", edgecolor = "black")

plt.show()
```

I want to obtain a function `f(x,y,z)`, to figure out what the value `v` should be at any arbitrary position. Simple, right? Then why can't I for the love of scipy figure out how to do this?

The examples I've found define x, y, z, define a nice grid of some sorts and evaluate to obtain `v` in the correct shape and order. This is where my 
tries break down. What if all data is initially formatted as 1D?

I thought I could do

```
V = zeros((len(x),len(y),len(z)))
for i in range(len(x)):
    V[i, None, None] = v[i]
    for j in range(len(y)):
        V[None, j, None] = v[j]
        for k in range(len(z)):
            V[None, None, k] = v[k]

fn = RegularGridInterpolator((x,y,z), V)
```

But this returns `ValueError: The points in dimension 0 must be strictly ascending`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html), here is an example using your data,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import numpy as np

x = [0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.02,0.46,0.46,0.46,0.46,0.46,0.46,0.46,0.46,0.46,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.9,]
y = [0.01,0.01,0.01,0.255,0.255,0.255,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.255,0.255,0.255,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.255,0.255,0.255,0.5,0.5,0.5,]
z = [0.,0.1,0.2,0.,0.1,0.2,0.,0.1,0.2,0.,0.1,0.2,0.,0.1,0.2,0.,0.1,0.2,0.,0.1,0.2,0.,0.1,0.2,0.,0.1,0.2]
v = [0.,0.,1.,0.,1.,1.,0.,1.,1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.5,1.,0.,1.,1.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.5,1.,]
points = np.array([x, y, z])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))
c = ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=v, s = 100, cmap = plt.cm.bwr, edgecolor = "black", alpha = 0.2)

# This is the interpolation, use existing points and values (1D)
# to get the value at 0.51, 0.32, 0.12
p = griddata(points.T, v, (0.51, 0.32, 0.12))
ax.scatter(0.51, 0.32, 0.12, s=100, c=[p], cmap = plt.cm.bwr)

#Plot a meshgrid of interpolated values (optional)
pad = 0.02
xg = np.linspace(min(x)-pad, max(x)+pad,10)
yg = np.linspace(min(y)-pad, max(y)+pad,10)
zg = np.linspace(min(z)-pad, max(z)+pad,10)
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(xg, yg, zg)
vinterp = griddata(points.T, v, (X, Y, Z))
ci = ax.scatter(X.ravel(), Y.ravel(), Z.ravel(), c=vinterp.ravel(), s=10, cmap = plt.cm.bwr, edgecolor = "black", alpha = 0.2)

plt.show()
```

which looks like this,

[image]

with a grid of values plotted to show the interpolation and your example point.

Comment: Ah, *that's* the one. I also wrapped it with a `__call__` to make it a little more neat to carry around, like the other Scipy functions:
`class Interpolate3D():
    def __init__(self, x, y, z, v):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self.v = v
        self.pts = np.array([self.x, self.y, self.z]).T

    def __call__(self, *args):
        return scipy.interpolate.griddata(self.pts, self.v, args, method = "linear")`